# How to send email validations through Django?

Tags: django, django-views, email-validation

so, I'm trying to make a function in my django project that sends a confirmation key through email for the user

so I tried to do this:

views.py

```
def createuser(request):
    form = MyUserCreationForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect('confirm-email')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'An error occured during your registration')
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'signup.html', context)

def confirmemail(request):
    form = MyUserCreationForm() 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyUserCreationForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            user = User.objects.get(email=email)
            subject = 'Confirm your email' 
            from_email = 'myemail@gmail.com'
            email = [email]
            recipient_list = email
            return send_mail(subject, 'Use %s to confirm your email.' % request.user.confirmation_key, from_email, recipient_list)
        user.confirm_email(user.confirmation_key)
    
        
        if user.is_confirmed == True:
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.username = request.user.username.lower()
            user.save()
            login(request,user)
            return redirect('home')
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'emailconfirm.html', context)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from simple_email_confirmation.models import SimpleEmailConfirmationUserMixin
class User(SimpleEmailConfirmationUserMixin, AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name','username']
```

I tried to make everything but it didn't work. I don't receive any error but also I don't send any email

Comment: The only place you appear to assign a value to `user` is inside a conditional `if user.is_confirmed == True:`.  How were you expecting that to work?  How could something be confirmed, that doesn't even exist yet?

Comment: Hello. I already solved that adding user. BUT my code does not seems to work, I'm not sending any email at all. Do you have an idea how could I send email validations with django? (check out my edited question)